# How to read a config file with Python's configparser?

Tags: python, python-3.7, configparser

I'm working on reading an external config file in Python(3.7) using the module `configparser`.

Here is my sample configuration file `config.ini`

```
[ABC]
ch0 = "C:/Users/utility/ABC-ch0.txt"
ch1 = "C:/Users/utility/ABC-ch1.txt"

[settings]
script = "C:/Users/OneDrive/utility/xxxx.exe"
settings = "C:/Users/OneDrive/xxxxxxConfig.xml"
```

Here is the sample code I tried:

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()

config.read('config.ini')
ch0 = config.get('ABC','ch0')
print(ch0)
```

And here is the error code I am getting, not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
NoSectionError: No section: 'ABC'
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Print out the the return value of `config.read('config.ini')` and post the result.

Comment: Code works for me perfectly fine with the sample ini you provided for `python 3.7` for me

Comment: I would suspect that, as you give a relative path for the config file you are not reading the expected one. You should add a debug print with `print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: Is your python file and the config.ini in the same path? if not, place your config.ini in the path of your python file. and then run the script. it should work

Comment: Yes, for e.g if I provide the wrong path, e.g. config.read('/xyz/config.ini'), I do get the error configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'ABC', so provide the correct path to config.ini and you should be fine! I tried that in my answer below and it works! Check it out! @pbch

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code is absolutely fine.

This line:

```
config.read('config.ini')
```

tries to read the file from the same directory as the .py file you're running. So you have 3 options:

1. move the config.ini file to be next to the .py file
2. use a correct relative path when reading the file
3. use an absolute path when reading the file (not recommended for portability reasons)

Comment: thanks for the help, that worked , it was issue with config.ini pointing to the wrong location.

Comment: @Pbch Glad I could help :)

Comment: Hi @Pbch I saw you accepted and then unaccepted my answer,  did something not work in my answer?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the issue is not finding `config.ini` in the correct location, you can avoid that by doing [os.getcwd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd).

```
import configparser
import os
config = configparser.ConfigParser()

#Get the absolute path of ini file by doing os.getcwd() and joining it to config.ini
ini_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'config.ini')
config.read(ini_path)
ch0 = config.get('ABC','ch0')
print(ch0)
#"C:/Users/utility/ABC-ch0.txt"
```

Comment: thanks for the help, that worked , it was issue with config.ini pointing to the wrong location.

Comment: No worries! I saw you accepted and then unaccepted my answer @Pbch did something not work in my answer?